# Apache commons logging configuration

Tags: java, apache, logging, apache-commons-logging

I am pretty new to java logging mechanisms, and I am now trying to use apache commons logging for my project. It's a Java EE project and the EAR file is deployed to WebLogic server. Basically, I want to use java.util.logging implementation, and I have commons-logging.properties file defined as below

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = testLog.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=SEVERE

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

For the packaging, I've put commons-logging.properties file to the lib directory of my EAR file. However, all my loggin output is printed toconsole instead of the log file specified in the configuration. Could anyone provide any suggestion or did I miss out anything in my configuration?

Comment: Use slf4j http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=503

Comment: Yes, use slf4j + logback http://logback.qos.ch

Comment: Agree with @Bozho, go for slf4j. And don't waste your time with java.util.logging -- logback is great.

Comment: @Kyle Mahan, you have justify your statement on why not to use `java.util.logging` vs SLF4J.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: From the official web site: The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time. - So you can change logging implementation when you need it.

Comment: @Vladislav Bauer, I know what SLF4J was built for. My statement was just to open Kyle's mind in bringing constructive comments and not just "stating".

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman You're right and I appreciate the constructive criticism. Personally I found jul's configuration to be very clunky. That you use java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=WARN to configure the handler and org.foo.Bar.level=WARN to configure the named logger seems very ugly to me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html), commons-logging.properties must exists in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Yes, that's why I've put the properties file in the lib directory of my EAR file. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: I would suggest moving it to classes, then it's found in the `ClassLoader` when pulled as a stream.

Comment: Has this ever been solved? I'm using this over other logging libs because i'm using pdfbox, and it uses this. but my properties file is not being detected at all. How do I change this?

Comment: @user2223059 please ask another SO question, specifying your project structure and posting any exception that your application throws.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename "common-logging.properties" file as "commons-logging.properties".

Comment: Sorry it was a typo :D The file name is commons-logging.properties.